# Bash String Replacing ""

Tags: bash

I'm doing my first bash coding and I have a String like this :

```
""987653547660485627"",""987653547660485626"",""987653547660485625""
```

Is there any way to change every iteration of `""` into singles to make it look like:

```
"987653547660485627","987653547660485626","987653547660485625"
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*sed* can replace string pattern:

```sh
orig='""987653547660485627"",""987653547660485626"",""987653547660485625""'
echo $orig | sed 's/""/"/g'
```

Will yield:

`"987653547660485627","987653547660485626","987653547660485625"`

The description of the argument to *sed* is "Replace every instance of "" with ", including multiple times in each row"

Comment: a). it can be done in bash way. b) you don't need those back-slashes in your sed line.

Comment: Thanks, fixed part b.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you were facing the problem of double-quotes. 
You need to escape the double quotes:

```
kent$  echo $foo
""foo"",""bar""

kent$  echo "${foo//\"\"/\"}"
"foo","bar"
```

Comment: Rather `"${foo//\"\"/\"}"` with quotes around.